# can clFlush be retried if it fails?

Tags: opencl

I have a program that enqueues a bunch of stuff to a command queue and then attempts to clFlush() it. Sometimes clFlush will fail I'm guessing because it is either CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY or CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES. So my question is, if one of these reasons is the cause of the failure, is it safe to wait for a bit and then retry or will this failure persist?

Comment: interesting. the spec does not say much about how to reason about those errors. considering how OpenGL spec looks like I'd say it is 'safe', however hard to say if a retry can ever succeed. Q: why are you even guessing? should be easy to determine which one it is...

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll just have to try and hope for the best. As for the return value, it would be extremely cumbersome in the environment I'm working in to try to get the return value, otherwise I definitely would have written it to print the error :)

Comment: If clFlush or clFinish return an error it's likely due to something enqueued before you called them. Try a clFinish after each thing you enqueue to find which one is causing the problem (probably a clEnqueueNDRangeKernel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered through trial and error that if the clFlush() call returns CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES, you can retry clFlush() again and it might succeed.